# How can I tell if an OSX program is running in the debugger?

Tags: c++, c, macos, debugging

Does lldb or gdb set any environment variables or have any other tells?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1361/_index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cribbed from [Google Breakpad](https://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/source/browse/trunk/src/client/ios/Breakpad.mm):

```
#include <sys/syscntl.h>

bool isInDebugger() {

  bool result=false;
  pid_t pid = getpid();
  int mib[4] = {CTL_KERN, KERN_PROC, KERN_PROC_PID, pid};
  int mibSize = sizeof(mib) / sizeof(int);
  size_t actualSize;

  if (sysctl(mib, mibSize, NULL, &actualSize, NULL, 0) == 0) {
    struct kinfo_proc *info = (struct kinfo_proc *)malloc(actualSize);

    if (info) {
      // This comes from looking at the Darwin xnu Kernel
      if (sysctl(mib, mibSize, info, &actualSize, NULL, 0) == 0)
        result = (info->kp_proc.p_flag & P_TRACED) ? true : false;

      free(info);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```